# Having trouble getting my bash script to be executable

Tags: bash

My script, `learn-fork.sh`, is the following, plus a lot of comments (which will be un-commented once I get the test lines to work)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running from ${0}"
```

In addition to that file, I have another file that shows in Finder as `learn-fork` (no extension) but that shows up in the terminal as learn-fork.sh-e

Here are the permissions on those files.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 TuzsNewMacBook  admin       250 Jan  1 18:25 learn-fork.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 TuzsNewMacBook  admin       307 Jan  1 13:38 learn-fork.sh-e
```

Running `learn-fork.sh` works. 
Running `learn-fork` gives `-bash: learn-fork: command not found`.

Comment: Re: "It's in `/usr/local/bin` which is in my PATH (though I'm curious about what looks like an error at the end)": That entire line is an error-message. You're running `$PATH` as a command, and Bash is complaining that it can't find a program at `/Applications/Postgres.app/.../.rvm/bin`. If you just want to print `$PATH`, you should write `echo "$PATH"` or `printf '%s\n' "$PATH"`.

Comment: If you want to invoke it under the name `learn-fork`, don't name it `learn-fork.sh`. Extensions should be used for shell *libraries*, not for scripts. Pretty much everything I have to say on the subject can also be found at [Commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Or, to use the way it's put in the freenode #bash channel's factoid: `ls` is `/bin/ls`, not `/bin/ls.elf`, so why would your script have a `.sh` name -- **especially** if it's a *bash* script, which is a different language from POSIX `sh`. Commands don't conventionally have extensions on UNIX.

Comment: If you still had a system where it *did* work, you could run `type learn-fork` to find out why -- if there's an alias or shell function intercepting the name. Suppose it's also conceivable your system could have a `command_not_found_handle` function that tries looking for `foo.sh` when `foo` doesn't exist, but that's an awfully janky kind of hack to rely on. (If so, and `type` doesn't find it, using `set -x` to enable logging should expose that... but again, you'd need a system where the extensionless name worked).

Comment: It's best to think of file extension as just part of file name.   There's nothing magical about extension in unix; a .txt extension that was in your path and executable works run just as well as .sh, .exe, or like Charles Duffy recommends with no extension at all.  The specified file name does need to be accurate - the extension can't be omitted because it's part of the file.

Comment: "I've tried chmod +x learn-fork.sh, a thousand times" this isn't magic,  just file attributes.  `ls -l` will show whether executable bit is set.   Blindly and repetitively executing commands can only further confuse things.

Comment: If the script's name is `foo.sh`, just `foo` will not run your script (without additional arrangements like an alias or a symlink, which of course then runs the alias or symlink, and only coincidentally ends up running your script). Your expectations simply seem to be unfounded.

Comment: Updated the post to hopefully remove some of the dumber things I was saying.

Comment: We have no idea what's in the `sh-e` file or why the Finder hides that extension. Either way, expecting the shell to ignore the extension is still misguided. Probably reconfigure Finder to not hide extensions if you find this behavior confusing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - ROTFLMAO - `"gods-kill-kitten.jpg"` (good article by the way)

Comment: Oh, dear -- I just reread the article and saw the `for file in $(find ...)`. @erlkonig, WTF? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invoke it with the command `learn-fork`, name the file `learn-fork`.

Exactly that, no extension whatsoever. Not `learn-fork.sh`, or `learn-fork.sh-e`, or anything else -- just `learn-fork`.

Treating a file extension as something separate that's not really part of a name is a Windows-ism; UNIX-y folks (and UNIX-y operating systems) don't believe in it. Thus, if you want a command named `foo`, the executable or script associated must be named `foo`, not `foo.anything`.

And it must be marked as executable with `chmod +x foo` AND called with a correct path reference, either `./foo` or `/path/to/foo` OR where `/path/to` is included in the PATH variable, i.e. `export PATH="/path/to:$PATH"`.

Comment: I went into finder and deleted the extension. Where that extension came from, who knows. Thanks!